# Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I have Spark configured as below in kubernetes. I followed this link to setup -
https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-spark-on-kubernetes/

[image]

Is it possible to run jobs in cluster mode in this configuration? Or can this be used only for local development?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Not all features are present since is experimental and more details can be seen here for full config and support: [Running Spark on Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#running-spark-on-kubernetes)

[cluster mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#cluster-mode)

```
To launch Spark Pi in cluster mode:

$ ./bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<spark-image> \
    local:///path/to/examples.jar
```

Adding details on how is used and monitored the jobs/apps when submitted and starting with: [A Deeper Look At Spark-Submit](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/how-to-manage-monitor-spark-on-kubernetes-introduction-spark-submit-kubernetes-operator) you can find the diagram and how does actually work. Also worth checking this info with custom images but the flow is similar [kubernetes-spark-job](https://docs.gigaspaces.com/latest/admin/kubernetes-spark-job.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to do the above and run in cluster mode. I was wondering the mode i deployed specifically within the cluster - if it is used only for development.

Comment: Yes you can, do you have master and workers ? Because what you have listed is submitted "job" that generated 1 driver and 2 executors actually for the job ...

Comment: They are actually master and workers deployed and always running. I can login into kubectl bash mode in spark master and get into spark shell. I followed the link the questions. I was wondering if this is development only scenario.

Comment: Not only dev scenario. This is in prod as well and any job you submit in your current cluster is will look the same for production too because is just images for driver and executors that are orchestrated. You can look at the pods or at app submitted and you’ll see the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in your configuration, spark is running on standalone mode (a simple cluster manager included with Spark that makes it easy to set up a cluster), and the cluster is not managed by Kubernetes. In this configuration, the master and the workers are Kubernetes pods, they are running all the time and ready to run your jobs, but this architecture is not recommended for production (based on my personal experience), and I recommend to replace it by Kubernetes manager which is now officially supported since spark 3.1.0, and it will be more powerful if you use [spark-on-k8s-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) developed by Google.
To answer your question, yes it is possible to run jobs in cluster mode in this configuration for java and scala, but if you use pyspark, you cannot submit the jobs in cluster deploy-mode, there is an alternative solution to solve this limitation by integrating a Livy service, which is deployed on the cluster, you can submit the job by an http request to Livy, and it will be the driver for your job (so the driver and the master/workers are deployed on the cluster).